# Group Policy Management Tool

Tags: windows, group-policy

This is a question about expected behavior when using the Group Policy Management Tool.  I don't entirely trust the results I'm seeing, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

Let's say there are two security groups: GroupA and GroupB.  GroupA is to have their desktop redirected using group policy to \ServerA\Desktops and GroupB is to have their desktop redirected using group policy to \ServerB\Desktops.  Let's say everyone is a member of GroupA at the moment.  When I run the GPMT Results Wizard for User A (as a member of GroupA), I see under the "User Configuration Summary" section that they were a member of GroupA in the "Security Group Membership when Group Policy was applied".  This is what I would expect.  Excellent.

Let's then say that I change UserA to be member of GroupB (and remove them from GroupA).  Now if I run the GPMT Results Wizard again, the member is STILL listed as a member of GroupA.  This seems incorrect to me.  When can I expect it to show the correct results, or what do I have to do to get it to show me accurate results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using planning mode instead of results mode. Results mode is going to tell you what the result of the policy application on the computer was, which will not have changed unless the user logged out and in again after you modified the security group membership.

Planning mode will take your change into account.

Update: mh's answer reminded me what the correct term is... "modeling".

See this for some pointers: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780305%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This could be the replication frequency time of your domain controllers, repadmin /syncall also under replication depending on latency and how many domain controllers every 15 minutes would probably work out best.

let me know if that helps, best of luck pk.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use the results wizard rather than the modelling tool, so maybe try that and see what happens.

It may also be the case that you have the GPMT output cached in your temp folder.  Worth a shot.

Comment: +1 for reminding me that the term is "modelling". ;-)

Comment: :) Pleasure to be of service.